# Wrong inference for reified type parameter in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

Given the following code in Kotlin:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.*

data class MyReply<R> (
        val results : Array<R>? = null
)

class ErrorClient() {
    val JSON = jacksonObjectMapper()

    inline fun<reified R> request(): Array<R>? {
        val json_in = """{"results": [2]}"""
        val res: MyReply<R> = JSON.readValue(json_in)
        return res.results
    }

    fun read(): Array<Int>? {
        val res: Array<Int>? = request()
        return res
    }
}
```

and the following tests:

```
import org.junit.Test

class ErrorTest {
    val client = ErrorClient()

    @Test
    fun `direct`() {
        val res: Array<Int>? = client.request()
        println(res)
    }

    @Test
    fun `indirect`() {
        val res : Array<Int>? = client.read()
        println(res)
    }
}
```

Short story: The first test passes and the second fails. Why?

Long story: I am experiencing a wrong type inference of the reified parameter `R` when calling the inline function via the `read()` class method, but the direct call to `request()` works. In the indirect case the type is erronously inferred to be java.lang.Object and thus the test fails with

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;
    at ErrorClient.read(Error.kt:17)
    at ErrorTest.indirect(ErrorTest.kt:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not about `reified`. I test the code with

```
val res: MyReply<R> = MyReply()
```

It does not throw any errors. This problem is your `JSON.readValue` return an `Object` instead of `Integer`. Kotlin try to cast it to `Integer` but it fails.

Comment: That only passes, because MyReply().results is null, which can be casted to any type

Comment: @AdamSzalkowski That is the answer. Your `JSON.readValue` does not return `Integer`. If you hard cast it by `val res: MyReply<R> = MyReply(arrayOf(1)) as MyReply<R>`, it still pass. It is obvious that  `JSON.readValue` is wrong.

Comment: My problem is that in the "direct" case it does return Int and in the "indirect" it returns Object. Why?

Comment: When setting a breakpoint in `request()` I observe the following:
direct:
`res$iv = {MyReply@2020} "MyReply(results=[2])"`
`results = {Integer[1]@2032}`
`0 = {Integer@2033} 2`
`value = 2`

indirect:
`res$iv = {MyReply@2068} "MyReply(results=[2])"`
`results = {Object[1]@2072}`
`0 = {Integer@2033} 2`
`value = 2`

Comment: So depending on the call it is either MyResult<Int> or MyResult<Object>

Comment: @AdamSzalkowski I don't know how your `JSON.readValue` works, so I can't tell.

Comment: `readValue` is definied in `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.Extensions` as:

`inline fun <reified T: Any> ObjectMapper.readValue(content: String): T = readValue(content, jacksonTypeRef<T>())`

Comment: @AdamSzalkowski I assume `val JSON= ObjectMapper()` but I have the same error in `direct`.